# How can I share variable values between different classes in C++?

Tags: c++

I've created a minimal example to share a variable between classes.

In C# normally I do this by creating a public static class with a public static variable... then I can just access it from everywhere.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestClass.h"
#include "Shared.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "This should print 'Hello'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Print 1 from main: " << MyNameSpace::MESSAGE << std::endl;

    std::cout << "This should print 'Test message 1'" << std::endl;
    TestClass test("Test message 1");
    std::cout << "Print 2 from main: " << MyNameSpace::MESSAGE << std::endl;

    std::cout << "This should print 'Test message 2'" << std::endl;
    MyNameSpace::MESSAGE = "Test message 2";
    std::cout << "Print 3 from main: " << MyNameSpace::MESSAGE << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Shared.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    static std::string MESSAGE = "Hello";
}
```

**TestClass.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Shared.h"
#include <iostream>

class TestClass {
public:    
    TestClass(const std::string& message);
};
```

**TestClass.cpp**

```
#include "TestClass.h"

TestClass::TestClass(const std::string& message)
{
    MyNameSpace::MESSAGE = message;
    std::cout << "Print 1 from TestClass: " << MyNameSpace::MESSAGE << std::endl;
}
```

So, if I set any value, for example `MyNameSpace::MESSAGE = "Potato"` from any file/class, I want to see *Potato* in `MyNameSpace::MESSAGE` from all classes

Here is the output so you can see better:

```
C:\Users\Adrian\RiderProjects\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe
Hello:
Print 1 from main: Hello
This should print Test message 1:
Print 1 from TestClass: Test message 1
Print 2 from main: Hello
Test message 2:
Print 3 from main: Test message 2
Process finished with exit code 0.
```

Comment: `static` in namespace scope does something very different from `static` in class scope.  Try `extern` in namespace scope, with no initializer, and then in exactly one .cpp file define and initialize the variable.

Comment: Usually the a global state like this is a bad idea. If you can avoid it, consider doing so. If you cannot, it may preferrable to create accessor functions, perhaps wrapping the data in a singleton object, since this can aid in debugging issues that may occur with shared access to the shared state. If you implement the accessor functions as inline functions, the compiler should be able to effectively convert them to direct variable access with a suitably high optimization level active...

Comment: using extern and initialize from another file .cpp worked.. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in C++ you can define public static variables in classes, and they will pretty much do what you want.

That said, use of namespaces here is almost irrelevant.  It essentially means that there's a `::` in the name of your variable (`MyNamespace::MESSAGE`), but you could alternatively call your variable `MyNamespace_MESSAGE`, for example.

So the question, independent of namespaces, is how can you have a global variable in C++.  One way do to this is to declare the variable in a header file, and define it in a single C++ file.  For example:

```cpp
// message.h
extern std::string message;

// message.cc
std::string message {"Hello"};
```

(Wrap these in a namespace if you want.)  Alternatively, if you just want to put it in a header file, use:

```cpp
// header.h
inline std::string message{"Hello"};
```

Outside of a class, `static` just means static linkage, meaning that you can't access the variable from other translation units.  That's not what you want.